# How to pass a list as a parameter to a controller in MVC C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I have a list that is bound to my view and I also have a URL Action redirect that I would like to take in that list and pass it as a parameter to my controller. I can see the list is not null when the URL action is called but when it hits the controller the value of the list is null

**My View**

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SearchTerm</th>
                <th>SelectedSearchCondition</th>
                <th>SelectedFieldToSearch</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in ListOfConditions)
            {
                <tr>

                    <td>@item.SearchTerm</td>
                    <td>@item.SelectedSearchCondition</td>
                    <td>@item.SelectedFieldToSearch</td>

                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>


    </table>
}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#loadSearchResults').on('click', loadFilteredSearchResults)
        });
        function loadFilteredSearchResults() {
            //alert('I have been clicked')
             window.location.href = '@Url.Action("DisplayFilteredSearchResults", "FilteredSearch",ListOfConditions)';
        }
    </script>
```

**MY Controller Method **

```
public ActionResult DisplayFilteredSearchResults(List<string>ListOfConditions)
        {

            ListOfConditions.Count();
            //ListOfConditions.Add(searchInfo);
            //var model = ListOfConditions.Where(x => x.SelectedFieldToSearch.Equals(SelectFieldToSearch) && x.SelectedSearchCondition.Equals(SelectedSearchCondition) && x.SearchTerm.Equals(SearchTerm));
            return View(new AdvancedSearchModel());

        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a list of object from a view to the controller in asp.net mvc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523119/passing-a-list-of-object-from-a-view-to-the-controller-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Consider changing your approach to POST the list to the server rather than using GET.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `'@Url.Action("DisplayFilteredSearchResults", "FilteredSearch", new { ListOfConditions })'`, Url.Action needs to use an object which has the property called `ListOfConditions`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_UrlHelper_Action_System_String_System_String_System_Object_

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest an alternative approach to `Url.Action`.  The reason is because where possible I like to avoid mixing Razor and javacript code as they don't belong together.  You also get the benefit of not needing to use inline javascript which is another bad practice.  What you are wanting to do is generate a GET request on the fly therefore my approach is to create a form with a method of GET.  Here is how it looks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loadSearchResults').on('click', loadFilteredSearchResults)
});
function loadFilteredSearchResults(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var conditionCount = ListOfConditions.length;
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.method = "get";
    form.action = '/FilteredSearch/DisplayFilteredSearchResults';

    for (var i = 0; i < conditionCount; i++) {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        input.setAttribute("value", ListOfConditions[i]);
        input.setAttribute("name", "ListOfConditions");
        form.appendChild(input);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit(); 
}
```

As you can see we create the form, set the method, set the action and then add the ListOfConditions data to the form and then submit. The browser then does the work for us by submitting a url with the required querystrings that the controller will then pick up and use to populate your `List<string> ListOfConditions` using standard model binding.